# Get notified when a specific wifi is visible in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I know that there is a REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE mode in android 4.3+ which let the device scan wifi even when the wifi is off. I want to know the result each time the scan performed and check to see if a specific wifi is available and if so do something. 
Is there any api for that? or the only way for doing this is scan wifi repeatedly and check the result?
The main constraint is battery usage.

Thanks.

Comment: I also search android source code but can't find where the setting actually used!